# c# ms access найти количество записей по каждому дню месяца

Tags: c#, ms-access

в таблице есть даты посещений и смена, 1-я и 2-я, в некоторые дни может быть несколько записей, в некоторые ни одной. нужно вывести все дни выбранного месяца с кол-вом записей по каждому дню, отдельные запросы для каждой смены, если нет посещений в какой то день то ставить 0

```
date        daytime
01.04.19    1
01.04.19    1
01.04.19    2
03.04.19    1
03.04.19    2
```

....

должно получиться
для 1-й смены

```
01.04.19 - 2
02.04.19 - 0
03.04.19 = 1
```

.... до конца месяца

для 2-й смены

```
01.04.19 - 1
02.04.19 - 0
03.04.19 - 1
```

... и т.д.

Comment: Ну, есть же в Access конструктор запросов! Почему бы не воспользоваться им?

Comment: вам нужно создать текст запроса, на count, с фильтром по дате!

Comment: @Bulson если бы я знал как это сделать то не спрашивал бы тут